# JDocumentRAW::addCustomTag() error on joomla component using jQuery.getJSON()

Tags: jquery, mootools, components, joomla1.5

i m newbie to joomla, although i have worked a lot with jQuery so i feel comfortable in jQuery rather than mootools, now i m developing a joomla component, so what i do..
on

> joomla/administrator/component/com_property/admin.controller.php

i write below code

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
JHTML::_('behavior.mootools');
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$rootURL = JURI::root();
$document->addScript($rootURL.'media/system/js/jquery.min.js' );
```

now when i go to add a property from

> http://localhost/joomla/administrator/index.php?option=com_property&view=addProperty

Actualy there is select boxes of province & city,on changing province, select box of city changes dynamically, i write

`jQuery.getJSON(?option=com_property&view=ajaxdata&format=raw)`

everythings was working fine  when i add `jQuery.noConflict();` on that specific page

**/joomla/administrator/components/com_property/views/addproperty/tmpl/default.php**

**BUT**  if i add

> $document->addCustomTag('jQuery.noConflict();');

on **admin.controller.php**

it display below error in firbug console

> **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined
>   method JDocumentRAW::addCustomTag() in
>   **/opt/lampp/htdocs/joomla/administrator/components/com_property/admin.controller.php**
>   on line **22**

please suggest me how to handle this problem,

actually what i want is

- i want o include jquery throughout the website
- also want to include `jQuery.noConflict()`, so that there shoud be no confliction between jQuery & Mootools( internally used by joomla),
  bcoz if i remove addCustomTag() method from `admin.controller.php`, then i need to add `jQuery.noConflict()` on each page where i use jQuery and that is voilation of *DRY* concept

please suggest me how to use jQuery in joomla without confliction on all pages of website.

Thank you for Support me always

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the noConflict call at the end of your `jquery.min.js` file? Or putting it in a separate file and including it right after the library?